# SwiftUI Animation onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.5) automatically starts

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-animation, swiftui-button

I've created a circular button which I specified to show scale animation on .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.5)
the code is bellow:

```
struct PlayerTouch: View {
   @State private var animationAmount: CGFloat = 1
   @State var animationEffect   = false
   
   var outerColor: Color
   var innerColor: Color

   let touchpulse = Animation.linear.repeatForever(autoreverses: true)

   private var outerBorderCirle: some View {
    let side:  CGFloat = Device.model == device.Six_6S_7_8_SE ? 108.6 : 146
 
    return Circle()
        .stroke(outerColor, lineWidth: 6)
        .frame(width: side, height: side)
        .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.3) ,radius: 8 , x: 0, y: 0)
        
    
}
   private var innerBorderCirle: some View {
    let side:  CGFloat = Device.model == device.Six_6S_7_8_SE ? 80.3 : 108
   
    return Circle()
        .stroke(innerColor, lineWidth: 20)
        .frame(width: side, height: side)
        .scaleEffect(animationEffect ? 0.9 : 1)
        .opacity(animationEffect ? 0.7 : 1)
        .animation(touchpulse)
                   

}
   private var touchCirle:       some View {
    let side:  CGFloat = Device.model == device.Six_6S_7_8_SE ? 71.7 : 96
    
    return Circle()
        .foregroundColor(colors.darkCream.value)
        .shadow(color: colors.touchCream.value, radius: 18, x: 0, y: 6)
        .frame(width: side, height: side)
        .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.5) {
            self.animationEffect = true
        }
}
   }



     var body: some View {
       ZStack{
        outerBorderCirle
        innerBorderCirle
        touchCirle
       }
   }}
```

and I've created 4 instances from this view in my main view like bellow:

```
struct GameScene: View {
    @Binding var numberOfPeople: Int
    @State var offset = 0

    private var touch1: some View {
        PlayerTouch(outerColor: outerColors[0], innerColor: innerColors[0])
    }
    private var touch2: some View {
        PlayerTouch(outerColor: outerColors[1], innerColor: innerColors[1])
    }
    private var touch3: some View {
        PlayerTouch(outerColor: outerColors[2], innerColor: innerColors[2])
    }
    private var touch4: some View {
        PlayerTouch(outerColor: outerColors[3], innerColor: innerColors[3])
    }

    var body: some View {
   VStack(spacing: Device.model! == .X_Xs_11Pro ? 20 : 40){
    
        HStack{
            Spacer()
            touch1
                
            touch2
                .offset(y: Device.model! == .Six_6S_7_8_SE &&
                numberOfPeople > 2 ? -40 : -50)
            Spacer()
        }
        HStack{
    
            if numberOfPeople > 2{
                Spacer()
                touch3
                    .offset(x: numberOfPeople == 3 ? -40 : 0, y: numberOfPeople == 3 ? -40 : 0)
            }
            if numberOfPeople > 3 {
                touch4
                .offset(y:-50)
                Spacer()
            }
    
        }
    
        }.frame(height: height)
        .padding(.leading, 10)
        .padding(.trailing, 10)
}}
```

and I have a button to add numberofpeople which leads to show instances on the view base on that.
my problem is animation automatically triggers after adding to numberofpeople
here is the gif of showing the problem:

[The animation problem shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmgWd.gif)

the right way of showing animation is after I touching it for 0.5 seconds

[Animation should be like this and should be triggered  after long tap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4aoq.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make animation active explicit per-value change, like

```
return Circle()
    .stroke(innerColor, lineWidth: 20)
    .frame(width: side, height: side)
    .scaleEffect(animationEffect ? 0.9 : 1)
    .opacity(animationEffect ? 0.7 : 1)
    .animation(touchpulse, value: animationEffect)       // << here !!
```